# making a bot using discord.py to assign roles to members based on status message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i want to make a discord bot which assigns a role called "supporter" to a user whose status message contains a string called "Testing" using discord.py. I am unable to find a way to get the status message contents.

Comment: Does your bot have the "presence intent" enabled?

Comment: Please post the code you are working on. Your question cannot be answered if there is absolutely no idea of what you are doing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, simply iterate over all members via

```
for member in guild.members:
```

where `guild` is the object of the guild you want to check.
And then get the activities of each member. You will need to check, if the activity is not none.

```
for member in guild.members: 
    memberActivity = member.activity
    if not (memberActivity is None):
        nameOfActivity = memberActivity.name
```

Afterwards you can check if "Testing" is the name of the activity. And if thats the case, assign the role:

```
for member in guild.members: 
    memberActivity = member.activity
    if not (memberActivity is None):
        nameOfActivity = memberActivity.name 
        if "Testing" in nameOfActivity:
            await member.add_roles(testingRole)
```

where `testingRole` is the object of your testing role.

You will need to have the presence intent for this to work!

Comment: Also, you don't need to check every member, just check for a single member in `on_member_update`, checking for everyone will definitely break your bot in big servers

Comment: Yes that would be the other option. But OP asked to check "whose status message contains a string called "Testing"". For me this sounds like he wants to check this right now, and not via the on_member_update event :shrug: